# Multiple files from one upload, resized and cropped automaticall - possible?

Tags: php, javascript, file-upload, upload

Is it possible to have an upload form which allows a user to upload a large high resolution image, and have it auto-crop/resize and save the many multiple items into a file directory structure?

Basically clients are going to upload images for various accessories, which need to have the proper aspect ratios. It needs to resize and crop the images and store them in a directory system organized in a way that the rest of the site can call the images for various reason (products, galleries, etc).

Is this possible?

Comment: Please revise your question to be specific. Ultimately one can answer `YES` or `NO` and satisfy your question of `is it possible?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) to create the images, HTML to upload it and plain old PHP to write the images to disk (and call the ImageMagick library).

So the workflow will be something like:

- Client uploads an image via a form on a webpage.
- The server which receives the image calls a script, calling ImageMagick on the server, to create multiple images, cropped and resized.
- The script also takes care of storing the images in the server's file system.